# PUT request method not working retrofit 2 android

Tags: android, retrofit2, put

All request method is working fine, but PUT request method is never successful. Its working perfectly in 'Postman' with same parameters. My request calling interface

```
@Multipart
@PUT("api/v1/user/{id}/")
Call<UpdateProfileResponse> updateUserProfile(
        @Header("Authorization") String token,
        @Path("id") int user_id,

        @Part("name") RequestBody name,
        @Part("email") RequestBody email,
        @Part("password") RequestBody password,

        @Part MultipartBody.Part picture,

        @Part("city") RequestBody city,
        @Part("country") RequestBody country,
        @Part("bank_name") RequestBody bank_name,
        @Part("bank_account_name") RequestBody bank_account_name,
        @Part("bank_account_number") RequestBody bank_account_number,
        @Part("user_type") RequestBody user_type,
        @Part("address") RequestBody address
);
```

Request calling (enqueuing)

```
 mApiClient.updateUserProfile(access_token, user_id, name, email, password, bodyPicture, city,
            country, bank_name, bank_account_name, bank_account_number, user_type, address)
            .enqueue(new Callback<UpdateProfileResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<UpdateProfileResponse> call, Response<UpdateProfileResponse> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "update response: " + response.body().toString());

                    } else {                
                        Log.d(TAG, "update response: " + response.errorBody());

                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<UpdateProfileResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    t.printStackTrace();

                }
            });
```

its always finishes in OnResponse else block (not successful). Not getting any clue what I am doing wrong. Need suggestion to fix this.

Comment: there may be the problem with parsing the responsebody to your UpdateProfileResponse Pojo class. Use logger to track what you are receiving . You can also use plain ResponseBody instead of UpdateProfileResponse to check it.